# Ffmpeg configuration to stream the frames of my webcam

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build a server in NodeJs to stream in RTSP my webcam using Angular to retrieve the frames and connecting using websockets. The server side is using "express-ws" module to create the Websocket.

I was successfull in sending the frames from the webcam to the server in base64, the server is receiving these messages from a function on interval of (1000 / 30)ms.

The issue relies on the implementation of my Ffmpeg child process. I retrieve the message and convert it into a buffer to then write this in the function of Ffmpeg.

My current implementation is this one:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
exports.stream =  (ws ,req) => {
    try{
        const mess = `connection from: ${req._remoteAddress} at ${req._startTime}.`
        const initialMess =`Started ${mess}`
        ws.uuid = uuidv4()
        console.log(initialMess)

        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
            message = JSON.parse(message)
            console.log(`Res: ${message.width} x ${message.height}`);
            const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
                '-f', 'rawvideo',
                '-pixel_format', 'rgb24',
                '-video_size', `${message.width}x${message.height}`,
                '-framerate', `${message.framerate}`,
                '-i', '-',
                '-codec:v', 'libx264',
                '-preset', 'ultrafast',
                '-tune', 'zerolatency',
                '-f', 'rtsp',
                'rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/rtsp/stream',
            ]);
            const base64Data = message.video;
            const videoData = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

            ffmpeg.stdin.write(videoData);
            ffmpeg.stdin.end();
            
            ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                console.error(`FFmpeg : ${data}`);
                });

            ffmpeg.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
                if (dev) console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
        
                // Close the WebSocket connection
                ws.close();
                });
        });
        ws.on('close', () => {
            const finalMess = `Stopped ${mess}`
            rem(ws.uuid)
            console.log(finalMess)
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

In terms of the message received, this is the Angular side sending the message:

```
const imageData = this.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
socket.send(JSON.stringify({video: imageData, width: this.canvas.width, height: this.canvas.height, framerate: interval }));
```

The interval variable is the divisor of the interval that is triggering the function (in this case 30).

I'm currently receiving the error message from Ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)

FFmpeg :   configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

FFmpeg : [rawvideo @ 0x150005ff0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 0).

FFmpeg : Input #0, rawvideo, from 'fd:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn

FFmpeg : Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))

FFmpeg : fd:: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0x14ef24290] Invalid buffer size, packet size 76343 < expected frame_size 921600

FFmpeg : Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument

FFmpeg : [libx264 @ 0x14ef25a20] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON

FFmpeg : [libx264 @ 0x14ef25a20] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit

FFmpeg : [libx264 @ 0x14ef25a20] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=7 lookahead_threads=7 sliced_threads=1 slices=7 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0

FFmpeg : [tcp @ 0x1500078a0] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
[out#0/rtsp @ 0x14ef24b00] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Connection refused

FFmpeg : [vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0x14ef256d0] Error initializing output stream: 

FFmpeg : Conversion failed!

FFmpeg process exited with code 1 and signal null
```

This is the reason I believe the issue relies on the configuration of Ffmpeg and how to set it for this case. It would be great to being able to play this RTSP link in my VLC to conclude it as successfull.

I would apreciate any suggestions or guidence.
Thanks in advance.